# How to get the defined() value by a string?

Tags: php

```
define('key_start_atz', 200);

$str = 'key_start_atz';
```

How can I get `200` via `$str`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
constant($str);
```

Comment: How to get `$key_start_atz` from `'key_start_atz'` ?

Comment: You can use variable variables: `$$str`

Answer (score 3):

```
define('key_start_atz', 200);

$x = 'key_start_atz'; // contains 'key_start_atz'
$x = key_start_atz; // contains 200
$x = constant('key_start_atz'); // contains 200
```